# ggplot2 point scaling unexpected

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been playing around with size scaling in ggplot2 (in order to produce a legend for a different plots, that why my code below is so rudimentary).

As far as I can tell, ggplot2's `size` scaling scales points' areas. Since my values live on very different scales, I'm using log10-transformed values.

My problem: The legend on this plot looks completely off to me in that the dot size for 1e-4 looks way way too small in relation to the other values. In other words, never ever is area(1e-4) - area(1e-3) the same as area(1e-3) - area(1e-2).

Is there something I'm misunderstanding or is this a bug?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:2, y = c(7.579438e-05, 
                                        0.1282808))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, size = y)) +
  scale_size(trans = 'log10', range = c(0.1, 20))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need the `range` argument?

Comment: It is working correctly I think.  It looks like the area scaling linearly with `log(y)`.  What exactly do you want the scaling rule to be?  If you want something that looks nice try `scale_radius()`?